# UICollectionView cellForItem(at:) crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I am using Swift4 and Xcode9.

I create my collectionView cells by using the delegate method below;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mediaItemCell", for: indexPath) as! MediaItemCollectionViewCell
    cell.mediaItemCellImageView.image = mediaPlayer?.item(at: indexPath.row)?.image

    return cell
}
```

Then, I want to replace the image of selected cell with a "stop" image. To achieve this, I have tried to use `didSelectItemAt` method;

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if (mediaPlayer?.isPlaying == true) {
            // stop the player
            mediaPlayer?.stopPlayingMedia()
        } else {
            // change the image and start playing
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MediaItemCollectionViewCell // CRASH
            cell.mediaItemCellImageView.image = UIImage(named: "stop.png")

            ...
            ...
        }
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // restore the original image
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MediaItemCollectionViewCell
    cell.mediaItemCellImageView.image = mediaPlayer?.item(at: indexPath.row)?.image
    // stop playing
    mediaPlayer?.stopPlayingMedia()
}
```

Now, when I select the cell which is already selected (hence the original image has already been replaced with "stop.png") the code above works; i.e. the original image is restored, which is done by `stopPlayingMedia()` method.

When I select a cell different than the currently selected one, the App crashes. I tried to move the `didSelectItemAt` call out of the delegate method, but it did not work.

Surprisingly, the logical check `if collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) is MediaItemCollectionViewCell` succeeds when I select the currently selected cell, and fails when I select another cell.

I want to change the image of the cell, hence need to cast the variable type but it fails. Why does to cast fail when I select a different cell than the currently selected one?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I use `collectionView.reloadData()` to restore all the images to originals (I mentioned this in the OP - when `stopPlayingMedia()` is invoked). It appears that, if I add a `private var index:IndexItem?` to my `ViewController` class and update its value within `didSelectItemAt` (to save the last selected cell) and use the code below, the code does not crash

```
extension ViewController:MediaPlayerControllerDelegate {
// this delegate method is invoked when stopPlayingMedia() is called
    func mediaPlayerControllerDidFinishPlaying() {
        // restore the UI
        // collectionView.reloadData() -> this causes the crash, instead, I only restore one cell
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index!) as! MediaItemCollectionViewCell
        cell.mediaItemCellImageView.image = mediaPlayer?.item(at: (index?.row)!)?.image

        timeLabel.text = "00:00"
        progressBar.progress = 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: It crashes? What's the crash log? Also `cellForItem(at:)` returns nil if the cell is not visible, so clearly, doing `as!` after it, is not really a good idea, you should do a `if let` insetad.

Comment: What error message to you get?

Comment: I am getting `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error.  Why does the cast succeed when I select the same cell but fail when another cell is selected?

Comment: "Why does the cast succeed when I select the same cell but fail when another cell is selected?" Because if the cell is not visible. When it crash, is the cell visible? I don't think so.

Comment: @Larme, `print(collectionView.visibleCells.count)` gives 12 when I select currently selected cell, and 0 when I select another one. I think I need to clarify the "visible cell" concept first! Any explanations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following to create cell and changing the image inside cell on selection. Not crashing at all. Please check the implementation, It might help you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
private var isPlayingModel = [false, false, false, false, false] // initially all are stop, not playing

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
    didSet{
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
 }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isPlayingModel.count
}
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mediaItemCell", for: indexPath) as! MediaItemCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageVw.image = isPlayingModel[indexPath.row] ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "start") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stop")
    return cell
}
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    isPlayingModel[indexPath.row] = !isPlayingModel[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MediaItemCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageVw.image = isPlayingModel[indexPath.row] ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "start") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stop")
  }
 }

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 4
 }
}

 class MediaItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var imageVw: UIImageView!
 }
```

[image: Output]

[Check the implementation here.](https://github.com/ashislaha/stackoverflow-contribution/blob/master/06.%20CollectionViewCell/CollectionViewCellTest/CollectionViewCellTest/ViewController.swift)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing indexPath correctly to load a cell, that's why it is crashing.Edit your `didSelectItemAt:` method as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let selectedCell = IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: indexPath.section)
          let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedCell) as! ACollectionViewCell
          cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "3.jpg")
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection view indexPath has element `item`, and not `row`

Try this and see: *(let me know what does it print)*

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // restore the original image
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MediaItemCollectionViewCell {
        if let cellImage = mediaPlayer?.item(at: indexPath.item)?.image { // Collection view indexPath has element `item`, and not `row`
             cell.mediaItemCellImageView.image = cellImage 
        } else {
             print("cellImage not found at indexPath - \(indexPath)")
        }

    } else {
      print("collection view cell `MediaItemCollectionViewCell` not found at indexPath -\(indexPath) ")
    }

    // stop playing
    mediaPlayer?.stopPlayingMedia()
}
```

Comment: the code does not print anything at all, In fact, the`didDeselectItemAt` method just works okay.

Comment: So where is an issue, if it's not printing any `else` block statements then I think it should work fine, without app crash, right? Do you have any other issue with this?